# Need some help in creating this graph using Angular libraries

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts

enter code hereChart[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dIeB.png)

Need some help in creating this graph using Angular libraries. I'm using Angular HighCharts but not able to create the graph

Visit https://jsfiddle.net/6Lbvrwmf/2/

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Can't code it for you but if you have tried something you can add in the post. Help us to help you.

Comment: sure let me add the jsfiddle i have

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lbvrwmf/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not a standard one and will need some workarounds. I'm not sure what *Vehicle count* represents and what is the relation betwen them and *Average CC Days*. I've created a demo you can base on. The main assumption is using `scatter` series with modiefied `marker` and editing `dataLabels` using `formatter` options.

**Sample demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fm0ex14y/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.dataLabels.formatter
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter

​If you have further inquiries, you may reach out to me at any time.

Comment: Thanks the the answers but this is the same as I tried in my fiddle. But the expected output I'm looking for is the image mentioned in the question.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. I've edited my answer

Comment: Thanks you magdalena this was the exact solution I was looking for ... thanks for your help